# Movie in which the prisoner teach alien/monster basic elementary knowledge to survive

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a movie I watched many years ago in which I only remember a scene in it. It is stuck in my head for 4 days now and I really want to know the name of it.

The scene was when the main protagonist's party was capture by some alien (or monster?) to a prison. There they met a man who had been captured years ago. The man survive by teaching simple stuff to the alien/monster like English, making fire, math etc.

The prison was normal looking with metal bar. There may be some relationship between the protagonist and the man that had been captured? but I am not sure.

Anyway that is all I got. Please help.

Comment: What was 'many'years ago? When did you see this?

Comment: My guess is 5 to 11 years. The movie itself could be older as I saw it on TV. The alien/monster basically start off having no knowledge at all and learn everything from the prisoner. Also the alien is about the size of human.